# Ruby on Rails - Ajax call to display only new records in a list view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a list of bikes in rails view, the database for the bikes updates via a cron-job every minute.

How do I make an ajax call render a partial of only the *new records* that have been created in the database from the cron job?

For example:

Current view is all bikes:
Bike A
Bike B
Bike C

Cron job adds another bike:
Bike D

I want to click a link to make an ajax call to render a partial that adds Bike D only to the view

Controller:

```
def index
  @bikes = Bike.order('created_at DESC').limit(50).all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :bike_post_ajax }
    format.html
  end
end
```

View:

```
<%= link_to 'update bikes', bikes_path, :remote=> true %> #link to Ajax call

<table>
<% @bikes.each do |bike| %>
  <%= render 'bike_post', :bike => bike %>
<% end %>
</table>
```

bike_post_ajax.js.erb

```
$('table').prepend("<%= j(render('bike_post', :bike=> ??)) %>")
```

_bike_post.html.erb

```
<tr>
<td>$<%= bike.price %>0</td>
  <% if bike.posted != nil %>
    <td><%= image_tag bike.posted, :height => '200', :width => '200' %></td>
  <% else %>
    <td><%= image_tag 'y-u-no-guy.jpg' %></td>
  <% end %>

<td><%= link_to bike.title, bike.url, :target => '_blank' %></td>
<td><%= bike.location %></td>
<td><%= bike.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %H:%M") %></td>
</tr>
```

Ways I thought about doing it, but don't know how to implement is to store the last created_at date of the most recent item in the most recently rendered array, and then choose create an instance variable of only the new items in the controller which the partial will use when the ajax call is made.  This process would have to also update the last created_at date.

Again though, I have no idea how to implement something like this, especially how to make a last_created_at variable persist after running the controller action

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 1):

Store the date that the page renders.

`<%= hidden_field_tag 'render_date', DateTime.now %>`

send it over to the server in your ajax call

```
var renderDate = $('#render_date').val();
var deferred = $.get(urlToUpdate, {render_date: renderDate});
```

then in the controller query Bikes to get those created after the page rendered.

```
bikes = Bike.where("created_at > ?", render_date)
```

send those over to the client as JSON

```
render json: bikes
```

and add them to the Bike list.

```
deferred.success(function(bikes){
  var list = $('.bikes-list');
  for(var i =0; i < bikes.length, i++){
    list.append('<li>' + bike.model + '</li>');
  }
});
```

You will want to update the render_date on the client too.

Comment: Thank you for this, I am having trouble sending it to the controller, so I have <%= hidden_field_tag 'render_date', @bikes.first.created_at %>, now in my link do what should I do?   <%= link_to 'update bikes', bikes_path, :remote=> true %>.  sorry for formatting

Comment: Personally I would be inclined to do the whole thing in Javascript using jQuery.